# Automatically linking Github repository to GCP repository fails

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github

I'm trying to link a private Github source code repository to a Google Cloud Platform Source code repository, but whatever I do I get an error "`The server has timed out while trying to process your request.`" and end up with the state "`Failed to load repository.`". Any suggestions how to fix this are welcome.

EDIT: Seems like some backend system healed itself during the weekend. The same thing works now.

Answer (score 1):

The original poster updated his thread with “Seems like some backend system healed itself during the weekend. The same thing works now” and so indicated that his issue was resolved. It is possible that this issue was linked to a backend inconsistency that is now fixed.

Further information on how to connect a Cloud Source Repository to a Git repository can be found on this Connecting a Hosted Repository [guide](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/connecting-hosted-repositories).